# NoReverseMatch error Django with slug

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, slug

I'm trying to make the index view show a list of "Journal"s, with each linking to a view that lists "Manuscripts" in the Journal. I also want `journal_view` to be located at a slug for the name of the journal, and likewise for `manuscript_view`.

## This is the traceback I get:

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/journals/

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['social_django',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'journal.apps.JournalConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template ... error at line 8
   Reverse for 'view_journal' not found. 'view_journal' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : 
   3 : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'journal/style.css' %}" />
   4 : 
   5 : {% if journal_list %}
   6 :     <ul>
   7 :     {% for journal in journal_list %}
   8 :         <li><a href=" {% url journal.get_absolute_url journal.slug %} ">{{ journal.title }}</a></li>
   9 :     {% endfor %}
   10 :     </ul>
   11 : {% else %}
   12 :     <p>No journals are available.</p>
   13 : {% endif %}

# ...(Traceback)...

    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /journals/
    Exception Value: Reverse for 'view_journal' not found. 'view_journal' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

## The Journal model looks like this:

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    # blah blah

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse("view_journal", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

## My views look like this:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):   
    template_name = 'journal/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'journal_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Journal.objects.all()


class JournalView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'journal/journal.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Manuscript.objects.filter(
                                    pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
                                        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

## My app urls look like this:

```
app_name = 'journal'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<slug>/', views.JournalView.as_view(), name='view_journal'),
    path('<slug>/', views.ArticleView.as_view(), name='view_manuscript'), ]
```

## Project urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('journals/', include('journal.urls')),
    path('social/', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
]
```

Comment: Can you post your project `urls.py`?

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('journals/', include('journal.urls')),
    path('social/', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
]

Comment: You need to specify the app name passed to the reverse finction. reverse(’journal:view_journal’, ....)

Comment: Although I never did it from the view like that, it might work but usually I would do it in the template {% url’journal:view_journal’ journal.slug %}

Answer (score 0):

I had it working this way:

I defined a slug field in my model first, as you did too:

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

then in my views.py I did add this:

```
slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
```

and finally wrote my path this way:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', MyView.as_view(), name='myview')
```